# Pass void pointer to LLVM IRBuilder CreateCall

Tags: c++, llvm

I am creating an LLVM function call. How can I pass void pointer as an argument to that call. I have "_testFunc" as my function and need to pass void pointer as argument.

```
llvm::Function *testFunc= m_mod->getFunction("_testFunc");

llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(instruction.getNextNode());

llvm::Value *arg = argument is void pointer

builder.CreateCall(testFunc, arg);
```

So this `arg` has to be a void pointer.

Answer (score 5):

**There is no 'void*' type in LLVM IR. Use i8* instead.**

If you want to specify the actual value of the "`void*`" just create a constant integer and cast in to a `i8*` (It's kind of complicated for what it actually does but it's the only way).

Otherwise if you just want a type for `void*` use `i8*`.

Comment: I just want a type for void*. I am new to llvm, can you please help me how to get it as an argument for the CreateCall()?

Comment: Do you want to pass a void* value or use the type of void* in a function declaration. I'm confused with what you're asking.

Comment: If you want to specify the type void* for a variable type or an argument type use i8*. All pointers are the same size in memory so an i8* is equivalent to a void* when the program is actually executed. In the actual code the type would be represented as "llvm::Type::getInt8PtrTy(llvm_context)"